# Reputation Leagues

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

I know the reputation leagues are mostly fun, but:

- <s>Why did you drop the 'current user at top of page' feature (that was an excellent addition)?</s>
- Why are the 'this week' dates not aligned with the 'this week' dates in the https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/NNNN page?

At the moment (2010-12-31), 'recent' uses a start date of 2010-12-26, but the leagues use a start date of 2010-12-27.

The first question (now struck out) seems to have been a temporary glitch somewhere.  It works as before an hour or so after asking it.

Comment: The current user is at the top for me. Are you sure you're logged into to Stack Exchange?

Comment: It worked OK for me up until this morning - and it is back now (an hour or so later).  Dunno what glitched - my browser, SO, my brain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weekly reputation leagues now begin on Sunday to align with the `/users/recent` page.

Comment: Thank you - that makes more sense.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the leagues simply don't like early mornings - it glitched again this morning, but is OK again now.  Thank you for bringing the weeks into alignment.